# Extract latitude and longitude from the format (47.35275, 8.55709)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using

```
var decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath("mypolyline")
```

to extract the coordinates from polyline path.
Next I want to extract the latitude and longtude values from the coordinate which looks like this

```
console.log(decodedPath[0]) 
//    Prints
(47.35275, 8.55709)
```

How cant I access each value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns a [LatLng class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng). Try `decodedPath[0].lat();` What you are seeing is the ToString prototype function result in the console. You can view exactly how that is generated by calling `decodedPath[0].ToString`, and the console should return you the function used (including the properties required to access lat and lng).